# Why is 'while controller' not working in 'loop controller'?

Tags: jmeter

I need to implement this use case.
I have to use a *while controller* test fragment in a *loop controller* and then run a request. After that, I need to run another request which is in a *while loop*. It should repeat **2 times**.
Loop set to **=2**.

It runs successfully the first time, but the second time it just skips the *while controller* request.

Answer (score 0):

While Controller can be "skipped" only in case when the "Condition" is (or becomes) `false` so maybe your test fragment is setting some variable to false or increments a [counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) to some specific value.

I would recommend adding a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) as a last request in the Test Fragment and put the same expression you use in the While Controller condition as its label. Run your test and check the label using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.  If it's false - find a way to make it true, otherwise your fragment won't be executed second time.

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article to learn more about implementing "While" loops in JMeter tests.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by setting newValue to variable.
Added BeanShell post processor and added code like

```
vars.put("Id_job","newValue");
```